# Break string and display as 2

Tags: apex

i have assigned a string to a variable and want to display the string in 2 lines.
expected result:
[image]

Sample Code

### Vf Page

```
<apex:page controller="BreakString1Controller">

    <apex:outputText value="{!str2}"></apex:outputText>

</apex:page>
```

### Controller code

```
public class BreakString1Controller {

    public string str1 = 'Quick brown fox jumps \n '+' <br/>'+' over the lazy dog';
    public string str2 {get; set;}

    public BreakString1Controller (){
        str2 = str1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `Split()` function as well

Comment: You should just use CSS and word wrapping to achieve this objective, which you can ask about on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Use Following

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!str2}"></apex:outputText>
```

Controller:

```
public class BreakString1Controller {

   public string str1 = 'Quick brown fox jumps <br/>'+' over the lazy dog';
   public string str2 {get; set;}

   public BreakString1Controller (){
     str2 = str1;
   }
 }
```

**OutPut** :

[image]

> escape="false": 
>  If the String you want to display contains HTML
>   or XML-reserved characters, you need to use escape="false" so that
>   Your Chars and other characters are not interpretted as VF page
>   markup.

Also please refer to following question before using escape = false
[How to avoid security risks with escape="False" in output tags](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46804/how-to-avoid-security-risks-with-escape-false-in-output-tags)

Thanks,
Nachiket